# how to use application layout if using rails-api gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-api

I have an application for apis therefore I used rails-api gem. but now I am trying to create admin panel for it. There is no layout folder, no application.html file. I created it. But its not rendering. What I am missing?

If I use  `layout 'application'` in my application_controller it throw error `undefined method 'layout' for ApplicationController:Class`